# Unnecessary Horizontal Scrollbar in AngularJS/Bootstrap application

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar

I am trying to create an application using bootstrap and angularjs as practice and a simplified version of my application is illustrated in this pen: http://codepen.io/megadeen/pen/ZWrGmv

This is the main code:

```
<table class="main" ng-app="app" ng-controller="main">
  <tr>
    <td class="sidebar">
      <!-- Set page using AngularJS -->
      <a ng-click="page = 'fpage'">First Page</a>
      <br>
      <a ng-click="page = 'spage'">Second Page</a>
    </td>
    <td class="content">
      <!-- First Page -->
      <div class="fpage" ng-show="page == 'fpage'">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          .... Content ....
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Second Page -->
      <div class="spage" ng-show="page == 'spage'">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-7">
            .... Content ....
          </div>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, there's always this stray horizontal scrollbar that won't go away. This stray scrollbar only appears in the second and subsequent pages.

I tried adding the row class to the fpage and spage divs. However, if I do so, then the scrollbar appears in all pages.

Why does this happen and how do I correct this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `col-md-12` instead of `row`.

Comment: That fixed my problem. Thank you for your help.